# PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute 'BulkPageParser'

Tags: google-app-engine

[<class 'google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError'>: how to get around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325929/class-google-appengine-runtime-deadlineexceedederror-how-to-get-around/3327311#3327311)

using the code as shown in the former question link, I am now getting

PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute 'BulkPageParser'

on the production server logs after I call the url/script.  I had the program succesfully run before, but I cannot figure out what has changed, and why I am getting this error any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see a 'BulkPageParser' anywhere in the code snippets on the original question. You're going to need to include your actual code for us to be able to help you. Also see the caveats here about import path manipulation: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py#46

Comment: the code in the answer, there is a class called BulkPageBrowser, and we set job as an instance of that class.

Comment: and yes the error is being called in the deferred.py file, I don't understand why though.
08-03 07:54AM 35.339

Permanent failure attempting to execute task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 256, in post
    run(self.request.body)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 122, in run
    raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
PermanentTaskFailure: 'module' object has no attribute 'BulkPageParser'